# how to create xpath for the following check box

Tags: selenium, xpath, checkbox

I am finding it hard to create a relative xpath for a check box . I have attached the code snippet below. Firebug gives me an absolute xpath as:

`html/body/div[6]/div[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input[1]`.

But the form changes if there is separate entry and then absolute xpath changes to:

`html/body/div[6]/div[2]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input[1]`

(or tr[5] or any number). I tried to use the relative xpath but the firebug shows the xpath in red colour (so it is invalid)-

`.//*[@id='responderSelection'155939'1']`

Please help.

```
<form id="pollGroupForm" method="post" action="/consoleapp/newSurvey.jspx">
<div class="filter"/>
<table class="dataTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr class="alternateRow">
<tr>
<td>
<input id="responderSelection'155939'1" type="checkbox" value="true" name="responderSelection['155939']"/>
<input type="hidden" value="on" name="_responderSelection['155939']"/>
</td>
<td>twoway_2</td>
<td>                                              26161                                                           </td>
<td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try a partial search using cssSelector? I assume the numbers with the id is dynamic so the following cssSelector let's you find the checkbox with the partial match of the id(^ means starts with)

```
[id^='responderSelection']
```

If you really want xpath then contains() is the equivalence to the css above

```
//input[contains(@id,'responderSelection')]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to do this, depending on the exact conditions.

If there is only on checkbox in that table, then you can focus on that: `//table//input[@type='checkbox']`.

Possibly *safer* selector would be to look for a checkbox in your form, as that has a fixed id attribute: `//form[@id='pollGroupForm']//input[@type='checkbox']`. If you can, always start from fixed ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Xpath of an element which ID is changing dynamically, there is a little trick: simply inspect the element with Firebug, delete its ID by double clicking on it (delete the whole id parameter, or change the value to `""`)and you will get the correct Xpath.

For example if you have the following structure:

```
<div id="fix-id">
  <div id="dynamic-id-1214151"></div>
</div>
```

You will get `//*[@id="fix-id"]/div[1]` instead of `//*[@id="dynamic-id-1214151"]`.